# how can I find out the value of a resistor without knowing the current

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, kirchhoffs-laws

How can I find the value of R4 ?
[image]

The output at R3 is 1.54V

Comment: You need additional information, one could put anything there and it would not invalidate any of the informations you gave so far.

Comment: If it is a circuit you built, use a multimeter, but I guess you want to calculate based on some requirements.

Comment: simple answer: you can't

Comment: 1) If you "flip" R4 down you would not need the wire going all around R3 and the circuit would become a bit simpler to understand. 2) After doing that you'd see the circuit is basically a voltage source loaded by a diode and resistor in series. If you know the value of that combined resistor you could calculate the current. If you knew the current through D1 or R1 you could calculate the value that R4 should have. However, you do not have either value so you cannot determine the solution.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the output at R3 is 1.54V

Comment: You should indicate the 1.54V on the schematic. I didn't even notice it until I read your comment.

Comment: Are you to assume a particular voltage drop across the diode?

Comment: Is this homework? Need diode value

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgKqWl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Rearranged schematic.*

Hints:

- If \$ V_{NODE1} = 1.54 V\$ then what is \$ V_{NODE2} \$?
- If R2, 3 and 4 were all the one lumped resistor what would its value be to give the required voltage at NODE2?
- Once you have that you can calculate R4 using the parallel resistances equation.

Answer (score 0):

What information is needed to calculate R4?

- Voltage across R4: same as voltage across the series combination of R2 and R3. Which you can calculate.
- Current through R4 = current through R1 - current through R3.

You already know the voltage at the right side node of R1. Voltage at the left side node can be calculated if you know the diode drop. So current through R1 is also easy.